# arguments in the proc function in typo3

Tags: php, plugins, typo3, wizard

Please, give me the explanation of this function

```
 function proc($wizardItems)     {
            $wizardItems['plugins_tx_examples_pierror'] = array(
 'icon'=>\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extRelPath('examples') .'Resources/Public/Images/PiErrorWizard.png',
                    'title' =>$GLOBALS['LANG']>sL('LLL:EXT:examples/locallang.xlf:pierror_wizard_title'),
                    'description' =>$GLOBALS['LANG']>sL('LLL:EXT:examples/locallang.xlf:pierror_wizard_description'),
                    'params' =>'&defVals[tt_content[CType]=list[list_type]=examples_pierror'
            );

            return $wizardItems;
    }
}
```

This function is used in an extension to display our extension in extension wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best explanation you will find here at http://docs.typo3.org/TYPO3/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Examples/ContentElementWizard/Index.html

Hope that helps.